# Error Thread already started / scheduled

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

Friends,

I set up an AlarmManager within my application. The AlarmManager is scheduled to start a background Service every xx , here 1 Min. Its working quite well for a while. But freuqently I get an Error:  thead already started / scheduled. 
I have the feeling that i might dont use destructors correct. 
Would be grateful for your support.

Heres my code of the Activity that starts the AlarmManager

```
    PendingIntent pi;
    AlarmManager mgr;
    mgr=(AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i=new Intent(DataCollectionActivity.this, HUJIDataCollectionService.class);

     pi = PendingIntent.getService(DataCollectionActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
         ........  
    if (viewId == R.id.b_startService) {


        mgr.cancel(pi);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 1* 60* 1000, pi);}

            ........
    if (viewId == R.id.b_stopService) {


        mgr.cancel(pi);}
```

and heres the important code of my Service:

```
                      private Runnable LocationUpdateTimerTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.i(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name),
                "HUJIDataCollectionService, 1 LocationUpdateTimerTask, start");
        setuplistenerandrequestupdates();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(LocationUpdateTimerTask);

    }
};


            private Runnable SendDataStopLocationUpdatesTimerTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        sendDataToServer();



        mHandler.removeCallbacks(SendDataStopLocationUpdatesTimerTask);

        ServiceIntervalTimerTask.cancel();
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, HUJIDataCollectionService.class);
        stopService(service);

    }
};


            private TimerTask ServiceIntervalTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


        // remove old timer updates
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(LocationUpdateTimerTask);
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(SendDataStopLocationUpdatesTimerTask);
        // Start TimerTasks delayed
        mHandler.postDelayed(LocationUpdateTimerTask, 1000);
        mHandler.postDelayed(SendDataStopLocationUpdatesTimerTask,
                conf_LocationUpdatePeriodInSec * 1000);


    }

};


            @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();



    startDataCollectionServiceIntervallTimer.cancel();

    startDataCollectionServiceIntervallTimer = null;
    // Remove all kinds of updates
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(LocationUpdateTimerTask);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(SendDataStopLocationUpdatesTimerTask);


}


             @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    startDataCollectionServiceIntervallTimer = new Timer(
            "HUJIDataCollectionServiceStartTimer");

    startDataCollectionServiceIntervallTimer.schedule(ServiceIntervalTimerTask,
            1000L, conf_sampleTimeInMin * 60 * 1000L);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution for the problem my own. 
First i bypassed the problem by starting a Broadcastreceiver. But this is not an answer to the described problem.

Here is a solution:

```
                 public void pause(){           


        while(true){    

            try {                           // goes through this thread until our thread died
                ourthread.join();        //Blocks the current Thread (Thread.currentThread()) until the receiver finishes its execution and dies.
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            break;
        }
```

Thanks for the support anyways!!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you start a service it runs in the backround even when app is destroyed. Where and when you call your Alarm manager??? But if you often call a service i think that you will have memory leak or something like that...

Comment: I call the service from within the application. Of course when i close the application the Alarmmanager and the service keep working. but in a certain point it crasshes!

Comment: But why set repeting alarm? If your service keeps working why repet alarm? Just set one alarm and see if this will change anything...